# Need help on syntax error in CREATE VIEW

Tags: mysql, view, union

I created 2 views previously as below:

```
CREATE VIEW T22 
AS
    (SELECT anumber, AVG(slevel) 
     FROM SPOSSESSED
     GROUP BY anumber);

CREATE VIEW T23 (anumber, slevel) 
AS
    (SELECT anumber, 0 
     FROM APPLICANT 
     WHERE anumber NOT IN (SELECT anumber FROM SPOSSESSED));
```

Now, I need to CREATE VIEW that is the UNION of both the above views. I tried this statement that works perfectly fine and shows the result that I want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T22 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM T23;
```

But when I try to create a view for this it has a syntax error that I can't seem to identify:

```
CREATE VIEW T24 
AS 
   (SELECT * 
    FROM T22 
    UNION 
    SELECT * 
    FROM T23);
```

Comment: And the error message is?

Comment: Error 1064, a syntax error. Found out the problem, apparently it's a bug the solution was to remove the parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the problem on my own, opps!

The solution was to just remove the parenthesis and the syntax error was gone:

```
CREATE VIEW T24 AS SELECT* FROM T22 UNION SELECT * FROM T23;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict in the naming schema of the columns, you cannot use `SELECT *` in this situation. You can however change the `anumber` and alias it to a different name. To fix the problem.

Something like:

```
CREATE VIEW T24
AS
(
        SELECT anumber AS anumber1,
            AVG(slevel)
        FROM T22

        UNION

        SELECT anumber,
            slevel
        FROM T23
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the datatypes in table t22 and table t23 match?
Do the number of columns match?
Please post the error you are getting.